# Buttons not at end of content

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to fix a problem on this website which basically puts the "buy now" buttons far below the content. My friend asked if I could help, and I am just wondering if it would be a structural problem with the  tags, or does it require much css work? I'll post a pic with the dev inspector of the elements in question below. Thanks....and any help/pointers are appreciated.

Link to site if you want to look at the problem:

http://www.lovinghomecareservices.com/shop/

[image: buttons in question]

Answer (score 0):

On your foundation.css replace the following:

Line 9374:

```
.post-column-outer .product-post-column .content-buy-now {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  margin: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  height: 50px;
  width: 99%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
}
```

With:

```
.post-column-outer .product-post-column .content-buy-now {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  margin: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  height: 50px;
  width: 99%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

On another note, you have some sort of JavaScript-based function adding the height automatically.

Comment: thanks , I will try. Just one question, how did you come to that answer? (so I can understand myself). Thanks!

Comment: Get google chrome, you can hover over the elements in the Inspect Element viewer and simply untick some of the classes that cause conflict.

Comment: Thanks, I'll search for a tutorial for Chromes dev tools

Answer (score 0):

problem comes from your css.
you put this :

```css
.content-buy-now {
bottom: 0%;
margin: 15px;
}
```

remove it, and you'll solve your problem.
you can also use "inspect element" on your browser to check if there is something wrong with your css.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have an idea how I could make the button click toggle the content, lets say with a "read more" button that when clicked will display the content in the <p> tag?

Comment: A little onclick function() would help I think, by changing display style to block/none.